# My Resque worker forks do not disconnect properly from Postgresql once done

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, resque

My Postgresql logs are filled with the message:

> LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

After investigation, this message appears each time a resque task is finished by a resque worker.

I haven't found any resources on how I should fix it...

Is it worth investigating further? Could it be harmful?